# tipue search not displaying search results

Tags: javascript

I'm using *TipueSearch* on my web page, and I have the functionality of the search box and results page (as in showing up/rendering) working. However, the search results page isn't displaying the results of the page like it should be.

Here is the code for **tipuesearch_set.js**:

```
var tipuesearch_stop_words = ["and", "be", "by", "do", "for", "he", "how", "if", "is", "it", "my", "not", "of", "or", "the", "to", "up", "what", "when"];

var tipuesearch_replace = {"words": [
 {"word": "tipua", replace_with: "tipue"},
 {"word": "javscript", replace_with: "javascript"}
]};

var tipuesearch_stem = {"words": [
 {"word": "e-mail", stem: "email"},
 {"word": "javascript", stem: "script"},
 {"word": "javascript", stem: "js"}
 ]};

var tipuesearch_pages = ["/", "/approvals", "/search"];
```

Here is my **new.html.erb** page for the results page:

```
<head>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="tipuesearch/tipuesearch.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="tipuesearch/tipuesearch_set.js"></script>
    <script src="tipuesearch/tipuesearch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float: left;"><input type="text" id="tipue_search_input"></div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 13px;"><input type="button" id="tipue_search_button"></div>
<div id="tipue_search_content"><div id="tipue_search_loading"></div></div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tipue_search_input').tipuesearch({
        'mode': 'live'
        'liveDescription': '.header',
        'liveContent': '.container'
    });
});
</script>
```

Like I said, the search bar itself is just fine, and the results page is rendering like it should, the only problem is nothing that gets searched appears. I think the problem may be in the tipuesearch_set.js page, where I put the pages it can route to,

```
var tipuesearch_pages = ["/", "/approvals", "/search"];
```

but I could be wrong.

If you go onto the Tipue page http://www.tipue.com/search/docs/live/ you can find the type of search I am using and where I am getting code.

Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with, you're missing a comma (which I believe is required) next to `'mode': 'live'`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tipue_search_input').tipuesearch({
        'mode': 'live',
        'liveDescription': '.header',
        'liveContent': '.container'
    });
});
```

This should've produced an `Expected token '}'` error in your console.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch that. I decided to scrap the Tipue idea and go with a different method. Thanks anyways though.

Comment: @BrettCox Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Well, there aren't any errors, it's just not displaying results.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I'm going to try a different method of searching.

Comment: Which search method did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

you should set up the pages in "tipuesearch_pages" method to the complete URL.
ex: "http://www.yoursitename.com", "http://www.yoursitename.com/about.html" and so on...